# How to do unit testing retrofit api calls with viewmodel + livedata?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I just learned about Android unit testing. I want to implement a unit testing API retrofit call with viewmodel + livedata to my exercise project.
This is one of the viewmodel class.

```
class NextMatchViewModel(league : League, application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

// get idLeague passing for call getNextMatch()
private val _idLeague = MutableLiveData<League>()
private val idLeague: LiveData<League>
    get() = _idLeague

// next match liveData
private val _nextMatch = MutableLiveData<List<Match>>()
val nextMatch: LiveData<List<Match>>
    get() = _nextMatch

init {
    //get _idLeague value from argument(SafeArgs)
    _idLeague.value = league

    getNextMatch()
}

private fun getNextMatch() {

    idLeague.value?.idLeague?.let {
        LeagueApi.retrofitService.getNextMatch(it).enqueue(object : Callback<MatchResponse>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<MatchResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d(TAG, t.message!!)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<MatchResponse>, response: Response<MatchResponse>) {
                _nextMatch.value = response.body()?.events
                Log.d(TAG, "success")
            }

        })
    }
}

companion object {
    private val TAG = NextMatchViewModel::class.java.simpleName
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

According to Clean architecture approach your ViewModel code have not to contain any Framework related code. Especially reference on Application. LeagueApi is not a part of Presentation layer. You may solve it like: create UseCase or Interactor, inject it in viewModel, use Repository pattern, inject it in UseCase or Interactor, inject your LeagueApi into your repository and do all necessary work there.

This link may be helpful: https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-implement-a-clean-architecture-on-android-2e5e8c8e81fe

Good architecture will make your code testable. Hope it'll help :)

Comment: this codelabs tutorial explains how to get the application context [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-testing-basics/index.html?index=..%2F..index#7)

Comment: I see, but it is terrible way to do so. It violates 5th principle of SOLID as well as Clean architecture approach. This tutorial could be appropriate for old bad legacy code but not for new one. When ViewModel code not contain any Android related code and when you depend from abstraction, not realisation, unit testing and TDD become very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need a unit test for your API requests! When you need to access to your storage or network, you need to provide some instrument tests for your code.